# How do you set the most efficient parameters for ThreadPoolExecutor and ProcessPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

If I understand correctly, for `ProcessPool` you use it when you're CPU limited. So if I'm quad core, does that mean the most efficient max_workers is 4? And how do I know which is the most efficient for `ThreadPool`, because if I understand correctly it should be used when you're I/O bound?

This is using the inbuilt functions from python's `concurrent.futures`.

Comment: For cpu bound ProcessPool, 4 is the max (after that they just compete for time) but you may find that fewer is faster, depending on other load on your machine. For I/O bound ThreadPool, its all about response time of the thing you are waiting for. Reads from disk (fast, few workers) verses remote web scraping (slower, more workers) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tdelaney's comment!

You have to measure it.

---

I usually use an approach like tdelaney outlined to get the general feel for the program.  Is the bulk of your program parsing JSON or HTML? than it is CPU bound.  Is it making db/http/network requests? IO bound

Then I parameterize all worker / process /thread pools to allow them to be configured from startup.  Tests are then performed using the analysis from tdelaney to determine what the default configuration values should be.  Afterwards a [workload is applied and measured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing), processing latencies, throughput, errors, etc.  Then the config options are tweaked, and the same workload is applied.

---

There are many great tools for performance testing:

- [`ab`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html)
- [`vegeta`](https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta)
- [`siege`](https://github.com/JoeDog/siege)
- message queues/brokers often expose an http interfaces, so a backlog can be loaded using one of the tools above, or applied at a consistent throughput rate